# Compiling OpenGL on OS X Yosemite

Tags: macos, opengl, c++11

I'm trying to compile a [Hello Triangle](http://www.learnopengl.com/code_viewer.php?code=getting-started/hellotriangle) exercise on OS X Yosemite.  It compiles fine on my Ubuntu machine.  It actually compiles fine on Yosemite but when I run it I get a Seg Fault.  I'm new to OS X so am I not including something in the compilation?  I'm using `glfw` and `glew`.

```
g++ main.cpp -I/usr/local/include -I/opt/X11/include -L/usr/local/lib -I/opt/X11/lib -w -std=c++11 -framework OpenGL -lglfw3 -lglew -o main
```

Comment: why don't you take a look at the segfault core? compile with debug symbols, for example with `-g` and then launch gdb with the executable and the core: `gdb main core`

Comment: @Goens There's no `gdb` on Yosemite anymore. Use `lldb` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The segflaut happens because your GLFWwindow is not created. So window is a null pointer. For easier debugging, you should check this in your code before calling glfwMakeContextCurrent(). For instance like this :

```
GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "LearnOpenGL", nullptr, nullptr);
if (!window)
{
    glfwTerminate();
    std::cerr << "Failed to create glfw window \n";
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
```

Now, to solve the actual problem, you need to specify that your context should be forward compatible as explained in [GLFW faq](http://www.glfw.org/faq.html)

> The only OpenGL 3.x and 4.x contexts currently supported by OS X are forward-compatible, core profile contexts. The supported versions are 3.2 on 10.7 Lion and 3.3 and 4.1 on 10.9 Mavericks. In all cases, your GPU needs to support the specified OpenGL version for context creation to succeed.
>
> To create either an OpenGL 3.2 or later context, you should set the following hints:

```
 glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
 glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
 glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
 glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
```

If you want to know more detail about forward compatibility, you should check OpenGL documentation.

Also, your compilation command should not work since it does not call all the frameworks required by GLFW as explained in [building section](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/build.html)on GLFW documentation.